# invoke a action from within a action

Tags: openwhisk

Is there an example of how to invoke an action from within an action?

All the hello world examples use the cli to invoke them. Where do I start when I want to programmatically invoke an action. Do we use the rest API and what would then be the api-host?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node.js to implement the functions you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/openwhisk. The REST API is documented here https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/rest_api.md.

Comment: What if I use java? Is there a similar java library?

Comment: None officially released or maintained as part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to invoke ow action from another action, the "parent" action should be created/invoked with annotation **provide-api-key** == true.

E.g. if invoked using *wsk*:

`wsk action invoke myaction -a provide-api-key true`

Then OW populates the parent action with credentials required to communicate with OW.

https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/annotations.md#annotations-for-all-actions